# TSQL select one or many rows to join

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

This is question similar to: [TSQL select rows by one from 2 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208849/tsql-select-rows-by-one-from-2-conditions), but it is different in results that I would like to have

I have a table like so:

```
ORDER_ID   CODE1   CODE2   CODE3   STATUS    TYPE        SUM      GROUP
1          '001'   'BIGP'  NULL    4         'company'   120      48
2          '002'   'BIGP'  NULL    1         'priv'      100      20
3          '001'    NULL   NULL    6         'priv'      50       49
4          '002'    NULL   'L'     1         'company'   1253     22
```

and second table like so:

```
ADDRESS_ID   ORDER_ID   ZIP       TYPE   ADD_DATE       CATEGORY     VERIFIED
1            1          '15-125'    'K1'   '2010-01-01'   'CLIENT'     1
2            1          '22-022'    'D1'   '2010-01-02'   'SYSTEM'     1
3            2          '16-159'    'D2'   '2010-01-02'   'SYSTEM'     1
4            2          '15-125'    'D2'   '2010-02-01'   'CLIENT'     0
```

Third and fourth table contains zip codes and city names like so:

```
ZIP       CITY
'15-125'    'Warszawa'
'22-022'    'Koszalin'
'16-159'    'Krakow'
'15-125'    'Lublin'
```

For every order that has

- status not in (4,6)
- code1 between '002' and '005'
- (code2=null and code3=null) or (code2 in ('BIGA', 'BIGP') and code3=null) or (code2=NULL and code3 = 'L')

If code1 ='002' AND group IN (48,59,60,87) I must choose a single address
(big thanks to Nikola Markovinović):

```
SELECT TOP 1000 o.order_Id
              , a.Address_Id
              , a.Zip
            --, *
FROM orders o
CROSS APPLY
(
 select TOP 1
        a.Address_Id,
        a.Zip
   from address a
  WHERE a.order_Id = o.order_Id
  ORDER BY case a.Type 
                when 'D2' then 1 
                when 'K1' then 2 
                else 3 
            end,
        a.ADD_DATE
) a
WHERE
 o.Status NOT IN (4, 6)
 AND code1='002'
 AND group IN (48,59,60,87)
 AND ((code2 IS NULL AND code3 IS NULL) OR (code2 IN ('BIGA', 'BIGP') AND code3 IS NULL) OR (code2 IS NULL AND code3 = 'L'))
```

For all other orders that meet top criteria and got code1 ='002' AND group NOT IN (48,59,60,87) I must select all addresses for those orders that have verified=1

After collecting those addresses I will be able to check if a specific post company can deliver my mail to those addresses (I will check in another table containing zip codes)

I was thinking about making union all, taking first select and doing union with second that will return all addresses for code1 ='002' AND group NOT IN (48,59,60,87).

But maybe it is possible to do it without union all?

This it the final result I would like to get:

```
CODE1        TYPE        COUNT_OF_ORDERS        COUNT_OF_ADDRESSES     COMPANY1  OTHER
'001'        'NORMAL'    125                    150                    110       40
'002'        'NORMAL'    100                    122                    100       22
'003'        'NORMAL'    150                    110                    100       10
'004'        'NORMAL'    200                    220                    220       0
'005'        'NORMAL'    220                    240                    210       30
'005'        'PRIORITY'  100                    110                    110       0
'SX1'        'PRIORITY'  100                    100                    20        80
```

So if my type is 'normal' I must check if that address for order exists in table having normal zip codes, if it has type 'priority' I must check in table with priority codes.

If code exists in specific table I add +1 to COMPANY1 column, if not to OTHER, so that sum of those columns must be sum of my addresses.

---

This is query that I've managed to do (with help of @Nikola Markovinović)

```
SELECT TOP 1000 o.order_Id
              , a.Address_Id
              , a.Zip
            --, *
FROM orders o
CROSS APPLY
(
 select TOP 1
        a.Address_Id,
        a.Zip
   from address a
  WHERE a.order_Id = o.order_Id
    AND code1='002'
    AND o.[group] IN (48,59,60,87)
  ORDER BY case a.Type 
                when 'D2' then 1 
                when 'K1' then 2 
                else 3 
            end,
        a.ADD_DATE
  UNION ALL
 select 
        a.Address_Id,
        a.Zip
   from address a
  WHERE a.order_Id = o.order_Id
    AND ((code1='002' AND o.[group] NOT IN (48,59,60,87)) OR code1 IN ('001', '003', '004', '005'))
    --I'm not shure of that top line, it work's but mayby it con de written better
    AND Verified = 1
) a
WHERE
 o.Status NOT IN (4, 6)
 AND ((code2 IS NULL AND code3 IS NULL) 
    OR (code2 IN ('BIGA', 'BIGP') AND code3 IS NULL) 
    OR (code2 IS NULL AND code3 = 'L'))
```

Comment: GROUP BY, with aggregate functions MAX, MIN, SUM etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might filter addresses easily (`[group] IN (48,59,60,87) OR Verified = 1)`, but tweaking TOP 1 would make things ridiculous (`TOP (case when [group] IN (48,59,60,87) then 1 else (select count(*) from addresses where order_Id = o.order_Id) end)`. So I propose that you do `union all` but for adresses only:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 o.order_Id
              , a.Address_Id
              , a.Zip
            --, *
FROM orders o
CROSS APPLY
(
 select TOP 1
        a.Address_Id,
        a.Zip
   from address a
  WHERE a.order_Id = o.order_Id
    AND o.[group] IN (48,59,60,87)
  ORDER BY case a.Type 
                when 'D2' then 1 
                when 'K1' then 2 
                else 3 
            end,
        a.ADD_DATE
  UNION ALL
 select 
        a.Address_Id,
        a.Zip
   from address a
  WHERE a.order_Id = o.order_Id
    AND o.[group] NOT IN (48,59,60,87)
    AND Verified = 1
) a
WHERE
 o.Status NOT IN (4, 6)
 AND code1='002'
 AND ((code2 IS NULL AND code3 IS NULL) 
    OR (code2 IN ('BIGA', 'BIGP') AND code3 IS NULL) 
    OR (code2 IS NULL AND code3 = 'L'))
```

P.S. If order might not have an address replace CROSS APPLY with OUTER APPLY.

Comment: This is an interesting way of doing it, but as I was writing in my question, I must choose all order with code1 between 001 and 005, but when code1='002' and group in (48,59,60,87) I must only choose a single address, in all other situation I must choose all addresses that have verified=1. So there can be situation that order has code1=002 but it has other group than (48,59,60,87), so for that order I must take all verified addresses. I'll try to tweak Your query and post it :)

Comment: @Misiu Great, thank you. My mind could not digest all this `codex is null or codey in...` complex conditions so i just left them as they were and concentrated on address retrieval issue. It was a long day yesterday :-)

Comment: Thank You again :) You really have skills, hope one day I'll have so skills too :)